# Updating node and values of YAML document with yaml-cpp

Tags: c++, yaml, yaml-cpp

I need to parse some YAML in C++ (sort of newish to YAML). I'm looking to use [yaml-cpp](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp). My objectives are:

- To create some generic/reusable utility functions to help parsing of this YAML.
- To be able to update a YAML::Node and/or add missing values (by specifying default values)

If I take some example YAML, it might appear as:

```
...
  comms:
    messageBus:
      remoteHost: "message-bus"
      remotePort: 5672
```

or even:

```
...
  comms:
```

Nonetheless, I want to be able to update YAML reflecting default values. So to read the above YAML, the code would look something like:

```
auto &nodeComms = get_yaml_node_field_or_insert(node, "comms");
auto &nodeMessageBus = get_yaml_node_field_or_insert(nodeComms , "comms");
auto strRemoteHost = get_yaml_string_field_or_default_and_update(nodeMessageBus, "remoteHost", "127.0.0.1");
auto nRemotePort = get_yaml_uint16_field_or_default_and_update(nodeMessageBus, "remotePort", uint16_t{5672});
```

so that if the above code is run on the second example, the updated YAML would now be:

```
...
  comms:
    messageBus:
      remoteHost: "127.0.0.1"
      remotePort: 5672
```

For both `get_yaml_string_field_or_default_and_update` and `get_yaml_uint16_field_or_default_and_update`, it's fairly trivial to create a templated function to handle reading different value types and inserting them if necessary:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template <typename TYPE_IN, typename TYPE_RETURN>
TYPE_RETURN get_type_from_yaml_node_or_default_and_update(YAML::Node &node,
                                                         const char *pchFieldName,
                                                         TYPE_IN nValueDefault) noexcept
{
    if (!node)
    {
        assert(false);
        throw std::runtime_error("Invalid node");
    }
    if (!node[pchFieldName])
    {
        node[pchFieldName] = nValueDefault;
        return nValueDefault;
    }

    try
    {
        return node[pchFieldName].as<TYPE_RETURN>();
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e)
    {
        node[pchFieldName] = nValueDefault;
        return nValueDefault;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        node[pchFieldName] = nValueDefault;
        return nValueDefault;
    }
}
```

The code I'm struggling with is `get_yaml_node_field_or_insert`:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
YAML::Node  &get_yaml_node_field_or_insert(YAML::Node &node, const char *pchFieldName) noexcept
{
    if (!node)
    {
        assert(false);
        throw std::runtime_error("Invalid node");
    }

    // TODO: Either 1) Return reference if it exists or 2) insert if it does not and return reference.

    return node[pchFieldName];
}
```

It looks as if the operator[] does not return a reference according to API.

```
// indexing
template <typename Key>
const Node operator[](const Key& key) const;

template <typename Key>
Node operator[](const Key& key);
```

Any tips/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YAML::Node is a reference type already, so returning it from a function doesn’t make a deep copy. It’s also mutable, so you can just edit it and the change will update the root node.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't appreciated the subtlety.